# invoke_result for template function with "auto" return type and MSVC 2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, type-traits

I'm trying to use `invoke_result` with a templated function whose return type is auto; and I have an issue with Visual Studio 2017

I get an error message that says "a template-argument cannot be a type that contains 'auto'"

The code below works perfectly with GCC, Clang, and ICC. It fails with MSVC 2017. Of course, I did set the c++17 flag.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename U>
auto add_auto_template_fn(U a) {
    return a + 42;
}


void static_test_invoke_result()
{
    using T = std::invoke_result< decltype(&add_auto_template_fn<int>), int>::type;
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "");
}
```

GCC:
https://godbolt.org/z/Vkn46P (works with GCC, clang, ICC, etc)

MSVC 2017:
https://godbolt.org/z/jCK1cO (fails)

Does anyone know if there is a way around this?

---

EDIT :

It does look like a compiler bug

If I add a line above that forces the compiler to memoize the type, it works.

https://godbolt.org/z/9Y8yUH

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename U>
auto add_auto_template_fn(U a) {
    return a + 42;
}


void static_test_invoke_result()
{
    auto f = add_auto_template_fn<int>; // This innocent line will "solve" the issue
    using T = std::invoke_result< decltype(add_auto_template_fn<int>), int>::type;
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "");
}
```

Comment: Does anyone agree with me that this is a compiler bug? If so, I will report it

Comment: I reported the issue here : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/423254/invoke-result-for-template-function-with-auto-retu.html

Comment: Definite compiler bug, thanks for reporting it (although you should provide the code _in the report_, not just as a link)

Comment: @Barry : I tried and tried again, but I fought endlessly with the javascript code formatter; and in the end I lost. I will add it again, even if not formatted

Comment: I tried, but I give up: I think that the js editor is buggy to the point that I would need to post another question in order to get it to format the code correctly.

Comment: @PascalT. Just paste it as garbage. It isn't customers' problem that the Developer Community code editor explodes when there are empty lines in a codeblock. (Disclaimer: MSFT employee.)